# Camera 2 manually checking if ISO and SHUTTER_SPEED are supported

Tags: android, android-camera2

I was trying to check if the shutter_speed and iso for different lenses are supported but I don't know how, at the beginning I thought I was checking for that correctly like this:

```
val capabilities = characteristics.get(REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES)!!
val canReadSensorSettings = capabilities.contains(
            REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_READ_SENSOR_SETTINGS)
val hasManualSensor = capabilities.contains(
            REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MANUAL_SENSOR)
```

then was checking for if(canReadSensorSettings && hasManualSensor) //then manual exposure can be enabled for this lens.

I thought it was working then figured out that on some front lenses both of those values are false but I still can change the ISO and Shutter_Speed

My question again what is the correct way to check for ISO and SHTTER_SPEED support for a camera device.

btw, I have seen this and can't get it from it, probably the solution is in this link but I can't get it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES

Comment: is checking for SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible some devices allow changing of exposure/ISO values even if they don't list MANUAL_SENSOR capability (note that MANUAL_SENSOR being listed means that READ_SENSOR_SETTINGS will always also be there, so you can just check for MANUAL_SENSOR).

That would mean they don't meet all the requirements for MANUAL_SENSOR, in some way, so there may be some controls that don't work, or work differently than the API requires.

So for reliability, I would not try to use manual settings if MANUAL_SENSOR capability isn't listed, unless you're going to test each device yourself to make sure things actually work.  Sticking to devices that list MANUAL_SENSOR means they are compliance tested to work as expected with manual controls.

Comment: That's disappointing, it makes sense tho :/

Comment: @Eddy_Talvala
 so u mean, I can leave the check which will make it work only for devices that truly support that but this will make me lose some devices that does work(they work but unofficially but I will lose them)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559271/how-to-measure-the-iso-sensor-sensitivity-from-cameracharacteristics