# How to measure the ISO (sensor sensitivity) from CameraCharacteristics

Tags: android, android-camera2

How to measure the CameraDevice ISO value, I mean I need something like:

```
cameraCharacteristics.get(SENSOR_SENSITIVITY)
```

In this case this function will return the value of the sensor ISO.

I know that the cameraCharacteristics instance created directly from CameraManager is not going to have this value, what I am asking for is how to know the iso for the currently active camera

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
   val range: Range<Int> = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
        .get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE)!!
    val max1: Int = range.upper 
    val min1: Int = range.lower
```

you can get min and max ISO range of your camera.